# Android Parse SDK - Securing credentials

Tags: android, security, parse-platform, credentials, api-key

I am using the `Parse Android SDK` for my app and I am doing something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    JSONObject credentials = readCredentials();

    String applicationId = credentials.getString("applicationId"); 
    String clientKey = credentials.getString("clientKey");

    Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientKey);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

As you can see, I must provide an application id and a client key. I am currently loading those from a `JSON` file. What is the best way to store these values in such a way that they cannot be taken if someone decompiles my source and can see that `JSON` file? I am assuming that a `JSON` file is a bad way to store these if I am worrying about security here. I have thought about obfuscating my code using `ProGuard` but that is not the best solution because my project is open source. I dont care if people can root their phones and `decompile` the source (jokes on them, it's on GitHub); I just don't want them to see those credentials. Currently, I am git ignoring that credentials file from GitHub, but obviously I can't do that for the actual app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store keys in app's build.gradle as follows:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false

        resValue "string", "app_id", "67604hghhfhfhgh"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true

        resValue "string", "app_id", "gfhdgldd6567567567hjl"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and you can refer in string.xml like this:

```
<string name="key">@string/app_id</string>
```

and now you can call like this:

```
android:value="@string/key"/>
```